# Render multiple SSRS reports in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

This service takes in a report request object that can contain multiple reports that need to be rendered. This code works but I'm not sure if I've implemented anything wrong. Note the `exportedImage.Result` makes this synchronous but when I tried adding async and await to the `Parallel.ForEach` it doesn't seem to work so this was essentially a workaround, that's why I'm looking to figure out if I've implemented this correctly or not. `_exporter.Export` is an asynchronous method.

Just FYI, when I tried to add async and await, I added it like so:

`await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(request.Reports, async report =>`

`var exportedImage = await _exporter.Export(_reportServerUrl, reportPath, export, reportParameters);`

```
var reportDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(request.Reports, report =>
{
    var (reportPath, bindingOrder, reportParameters) = report;
    
    var exportedImage = _exporter.Export(_reportServerUrl, reportPath, export, reportParameters);

    if (exportedImage.Result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not render report {reportIdentifier} with binding order {bindingOrder}.");
    }

    reportDictionary.GetOrAdd(bindingOrder, exportedImage.Result);
}));
```

Comment: No, you're not using it properly. Do not mix `async`/`await` with the TPL methods (`Parallel.`). They're two totally different approaches to scalability.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer for my scenario, would you recommend going TPL or only async await?

Comment: I rather like the answer that was accepted. Modern, clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's pure `async` example without any workarounds.

```cs
private async Task ProcessReport(Report report, ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> reportDictionary)
{
    var (reportPath, bindingOrder, reportParameters) = report;
    
    var exportedImage = await _exporter.Export(_reportServerUrl, reportPath, export, reportParameters);

    if (exportedImage == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not render report {reportIdentifier} with binding order {bindingOrder}.");
    }

    reportDictionary.GetOrAdd(bindingOrder, exportedImage);
}
```

```cs
var reportDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var report in request.Reports)
{
    tasks.Add(ProcessReport(report, reportDictionary));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I think if you could extend your answer with some explanation why we should not mix these two tools that would give clarity for the OP.

Comment: @PeterCsala updated the answer. I think OP knows that, the concern in the question: _it doesn't seem to work so this was essentially a workaround_, i just showed a proper implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case, would you recommend using TPL or shall I only use async await pattern?

Comment: @UsmanKhan I guess you can do anything with `async`. Mixing tools makes the code less maintaineable. But find the difference between asynchronous and multithreading, totally different things.